# class method in for_each

Tags: c++, algorithm, foreach

There is a class and event structure:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(): name("nx"), val(9) {}
    string name;
    int val;
};

class Base
{
    public:
        Base()
        {
            /*array.push_back(Foo());
            array.push_back(Foo());
            array.push_back(Foo());             //fill array Foo
            array.push_back(Foo());
            array.push_back(Foo());*/
        }
        void Define(Foo* desktop)
        {
            cout << desktop->name << " " << desktop->val << "\n";
        }

        void Oblem()
        {
            /*for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i)
            {
                Define(&array[i]);
            }*/
            for_each(array.begin(), array.end(), mem_fun_ref(&Base::Define));
        }
    public:
        std::vector<Foo> array;
};
```

how can I replace the commented-out cycle on the algorithm for_each?

I now have these errors:

1. error: no match for call to '(std::mem_fun1_ref_t) (Foo&)'|
2. candidates are: _Ret std::mem_fun1_ref_t<_Ret, _Tp, _Arg>::operator()(_Tp&, _Arg) const [with _Ret = void, _Tp = Base, _Arg = Foo*]|

Answer (score 2):

`Base::Define` takes two arguments: `Foo* desktop` and an implicit `Base* this`. You would need to bind the current `this` within `Oblem` to get a function that takes only a `Foo`. Also, `Define` should be taking its parameter as `Foo& desktop` (or better yet, if that is real code, `Foo const& desktop`).

A full solution using the standard functionality within TR1 (or the Boost implementation for it) would be:

```
void Define(Foo const& desktop) const
{
    cout << desktop.name << " " << desktop.val << "\n";
}

void Oblem() const
{
    for_each(
        array.begin(), array.end()
      , std::bind( &Base::Define, this, _1 )
    );
}
```

Comment: The "implicit" `this` should be listed before the other parameters. This will make the `bind` call make more sense.

Comment: +1 for thinking it through, I got a head ache just from the variable names. :)

Comment: @bames53: `Define` still has an implicit `this` argument that must be passed in, which is done with the value of `this` within `Oblem`. The placeholder `_1` is used to pass each vector element `Foo` to `Define` as a `Foo const&`.

Comment: K-ballo, you can do something like that was just a function pointer instead of reference?

Comment: @PointsEqual: You don't get function pointers to member functions, you get member function pointers. If `Define` is actually that simple then it could be defined as `static` to get ride of the implicit -unused- `this` parameter.

Comment: the functor your bind expression creates takes zero parameters. You probably want std::bind(&Base::Define,this,placeholders::_1)

Answer (score 2):

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() : array(5) {}


    void Define(Foo &desktop)
    {
        cout << desktop.name << " " << desktop.val << "\n";
    }

    void Oblem()
    {
        for_each(array.begin(),array.end(),[this](Foo &f) {
            Define(f);
        });

        // or

        for_each(array.begin(),array.end(),
          bind(&Base::Define,this,placeholders::_1));
    }

public:
    std::vector<Foo> array;
};
```